# Multiple dropdowns with same class name: only fire onchange event once

Tags: jquery

I'm rendering a list of alternatives to the user, and a few of the alternatives have a `select` with a class name of `.product-dropdown`. In my script I have an onchange event which looks like this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".product-dropdown", function () {
    // do stuff
    // ...
    // ...
)};
```

My problem here is that when the user changes alternative, both the dropdown from the previously selected alternative and the new alternative fires the `change` event, which makes the code run twice and as I'm making ajax calls, the API runs into issues. How can I make sure that this call only gets fired once, even though two dropdowns actually change? I've tried unbinding the change event with:

`$(".product-dropdown").unbind("change");`

but to no avail.

Comment: Use `one` instead of `on`. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I should have clarified earlier -- is there any way to make it happen for the last time the event is fired?

Comment: You should take a look to `debounce` and `throttle` mechanisms. It can help you.

Comment: Awesome, now I know where to look. Thank you!